# Indent tag of equation to the left

Tags: equations, align, indentation, tags

I need an equation in which the equation itself is centered and the equation number (a custom tag) is located more to the left.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%here the equation number is at the far right
\begin{align}
\tag{\text{tag}}
2 + 2 = 4
\end{equation}

%and here the equation number is indented, but the equation itself is not centered
\begin{align*}
2 + 2 &= 4 
&&\text{tag}

%and here a bracket remains on the right side
\begin{equation}
\tag{\text{tag}\qquad\quad}
2 + 2 = 4
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: that's fixable but I'll delete the comment (better just to redefine the tagformat (why do you want this seems abit odd:-)

Comment: I want to recall an equation and I want only increasing equation numbers to be at the far right side. Because this repeated equation has a low equation number I want it to be indented.

Comment: In that case I wouldn'tdo what I just suggested in an answer, just use `\begin{quote}\begin{equation}...\end{equation}\end{quote}` which (in most classes) will set the equation in a narrower text block/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Employ `\usetagform{indented}` to switch to the alternative tag format, `\mytag{...}` to generate the alternative tag, and `\usetagform{default}` to switch back to the default tag format.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\newtagform' and '\usetagform' macros
\newtagform{indented}{}{\hspace*{15mm}} % set the desired indentation amount
\newcommand\mytag[1]{\tag{\llap{(#1)}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 2 + 2 = 4 \end{equation}

\usetagform{indented}
\stepcounter{equation}
\begin{equation} 2 + 2 = 4 \mytag{\theequation}\end{equation}

\begin{equation} 2 + 2 = 4 \mytag{Message of the Day}\end{equation}

\usetagform{default} % switch back to default
\begin{equation} 2 + 2 = 4 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need this you can add the space to the command that sets the tag:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

zzz
\begin{equation}
  1=0
\end{equation}


\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\hspace{1cm}}}
\makeatother

zzz
\begin{equation}
  1=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

Or perhaps you are just looking for a quote that indents both sides:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

zzz
\begin{equation}
  1=0
\end{equation}


\begin{quote}
zzz
\begin{equation}
  1=0
\end{equation}
\end{quote}


\end{document}
```

Comment: When I use quote, the equation is placed 1 cm lower than originally, and when I use the solution with \makeatletter all subsequent tags are indented as well.

Comment: @Sven the quote environment is a display enviornment it sets off the quoted text with vertical space (although that's settable, depends a bit on the class, the definition in article class is only a line so not so hard to change) it should not affect anything after `\end{quote}`  the tagform@ redefinition is a local definition you can do it inside an environment or inside `{....}` or any other way of keeping settings local to a group.